# SQL Query - Need some assistance with a query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I have the ER Diagram attached below. It's quite simple. Product, product types, manufacturer and their associations.

What the query needs to do is return the last name of the manufacturers, and the product names of the products they've produced, under the condition that those manufacturers have manufactured products of at least two different types.

Thanks very much for the replies. They have been extremely useful and educational. I really appreciate it.

[image: ER Diagram]

Comment: You will get more help if you include some dummy data to work with.

Comment: This is a classic learning problem, if you don't do it yourself you will never learn. With that said I will help you with some guidelines. First you need to join the manufacturer table with the product table using the relationship table between them. Last in the where clause you can filter with a subquery that joins the manufacturer table with the product table and then with the product type table, grouping by manufacturer_id having count(distinct type_id)>1

Comment: Do your homework, and you'll learn databases and SQL.

Comment: Please provide sample data in table form

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing this is to filter your select by using a subselect in the where clause.  I did this really fast just to demonstrate:

```
select * from manufacturer m 
inner join manufacturer_has_product mhp
    on m.manufacturer_id = m.manufacturer_id
inner join product p
    on mhp.product_id = p.product_id
where m.manufacturer_id in (
    select m.manufacturer_id
    from manufacturer m
    inner join manufacturer_has_product mhp
        on m.manufacturer_id = m.manufacturer_id
    inner join product p
        on mhp.product_id = p.product_id
    inner join productType_has_product pthp
        on pt.product_product_id = p.product_id
    inner join productType pt
        on pt.productType_type_id = pt.type_id
    group by m.manufacturer_id
    having count(pt.type_id) > 1
    )
```

Comment: First get your main query working.  This will return all of the manufacturers and their products.  Then work on your sub-query, this is list of manufacturers that have more than 1 product.  Do these two queries separate for now.

Comment: Where you wrote "  on m.manufacturer_id = m.manufacturer_id"

Did you mean to say "on mhp.manufacturer_id=m.manufacturer_id"?

And on the part where you wrote "pt.productType_type_id = pt.type_id"

I assume you meant "pt.type_id=pthp.type_id"?

Comment: You are correct.  I did not want to make it too easy for you.   :)

Comment: I like xerx593's answer.  If you have time you should make it work that way.  It is a little harder to understand but I think it would run faster for large data.

Comment: Thank you very much, both of you. You helped me understand how subqueries work.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard without any data to look at, but here's a shot.

```
select p.Name, m.last_name from Product p
inner join manufacturer m on m.manufacturer_id = p.product_id
inner join productType pT on p.product_id = pT.type_id 
where COUNT(distinct pT.type_id) >= 2 
group by m.manufacturer_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @Eric's answer, not tested, explanation in comments...

```
SELECT tmp.last_name, p.name -- <- compose the final select 
FROM
-- sub-select the underlying manufacturers (id + last_name):
(
    -- distinct ... or join deeper
    SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT php.productType_type_id), m.manufacturer_id, m.last_name
    FROM manufacturer m
    JOIN manufacturer_has_product mhp
    ON (mhp.manufacturer_manufacturer_id = m.manufacturer_id)
    JOIN Product p
    ON (p.product_id = mhp.Product_product_id)
    --- until "php" is enough, but needs distinct
    JOIN productType_has_product php
    ON (php.Product_product_id = p.product_id)
    -- obligatory:
    GROUP BY m.manufacturer_id, m.last_name
    -- (aggregated) filter condition: 
    HAVING COUNT (DISTINCT php.productType_type_id) > 1
) tmp -- an alias for the sub-select
-- join for the final result:
JOIN manufacturer_has_product mhp
-- on TMP.manufacturer_id!
ON (mhp.manufacturer_manufacturer_id = tmp.manufacturer_id) 
JOIN Product p ON (p.product_id = mhp.Product_product_id)
```